# How do I change the color and lettertype in my fragments first code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am busy to build something in my first android app "a questionnaire overview". and I need just to know how can I change the color, letter type and size of the text view.

can someone help me to which code. I am very appreciated thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">
```

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="Overzicht"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="Overzicht"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:text="Hieronder ziet u een overzicht van de antwoorden die u gegeven heeft. Controleer de antwoorden en pas deze waar nodig aan. Als u de vragenlijst naar wens heeft ingevuld kunt u op Verzenden klikken."
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="141dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Color change:

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

See color codes here:[link](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html)

Font (Letter type) change:

```
android:fontFamily="name of the font family"
```

See font families here: [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts)

Letter size change:

```
android:textSize="xxdp"
```

xx is the size of the font.

You can always refer to this site for guides and documentation: [Android dev](https://developer.android.com/guide)

Answer (score 0):

if you want change programmatically using java in your **onCreateView** method inside fragment use:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_FRAGMENT_VIEW, container, false);
TextView tv;
tv= findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface font;
```

now if you want **change font**, first you open a asset folder and inside that add the
fontName.ttf
in **onCreateView** method inside your fragment add bellow code:

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName.ttf ");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

if you want **change TextView color**

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

if you want **change TextView size**

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
```